# Subscription Related Questions - Azure Pay as you go

Tags: azure

Can we merge multiple azure subscriptions into a single one?

Also is it a good idea to have a Standard subscription for the practice purpose?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer support / billing support question, not programming-related.

Comment: I would suggest opening a support ticket to discuss your options for moving resources between subscriptions.